# Convert Numeric value to Varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to fetch the records and append some letters to my numeric column, but I'm getting an error. I tried with cast and convert function.

For example:

```
select convert(varchar(10),StandardCost +'S')
from DimProduct where ProductKey = 212
```

here `StandardCost` is a numeric field, but when I fetch the record I get an error.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

i think it should be

```
select convert(varchar(10),StandardCost) +'S' from DimProduct where ProductKey = 212
```

or

```
select cast(StandardCost as varchar(10)) + 'S' from DimProduct where ProductKey = 212
```

Answer (score 8):

First convert the numeric value then add the `'S'`:

```
 select convert(varchar(10),StandardCost) +'S'
 from DimProduct where ProductKey = 212
```