# converting numeric to character in sqldf

Tags: r, casting, character, sqldf

I am trying to concatenate 2 columns of a data-frame in R using sqldf command. However, it treats them as numeric and sums them up. I looked at the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323361/convert-numeric-value-to-varchar)  to a similar question on stackoverflow but it still doesn't work for me.

Here's what my DF looks like:

```
SP1  SP2
521  526
521  523
```

What I want is:

```
SP
521-526
521-523
```

I tried the following:

```
sqldf("select  SP1 + '-' + SP2 as SP from DF")
```

I also tried:

```
DF2 <- transform(DF, SP1 = as.character(SP1), SP2 = as.character(SP2)))
sqldf("select  SP1 + '-' + SP2 as SP from DF2")
```

In both cases, the result I get is

```
SP
1047
1044
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although that will work in SQL Server, you will have to use `||` instead of `+` since `sqldf` is most likely using a SQLite backend:

```
R> sqldf::sqldf(
    "SELECT SP1 || '-' || SP2 AS SP
     FROM df;"
  )
       SP
1 521-526
2 521-523
```

---

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(
  text = "SP1  SP2
  521  526
  521  523",
  header = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Thank you nrussell. It works with just a minor addition. In fact cast does not work and before your command, I should convert these columns to character as below: 
    DF <- transform(DF, SP1 = as.character(SP1), SP2 = as.character(SP2)))

Comment: I have `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` as a default setting on my machine, in while case the above answer works fine.

Comment: It depends on whether the dataframe is has the values as integer or numeric. If numeric, you get spurious `.0`s.

Answer (score 0):

If the RH2 package is loaded sqldf will use [H2](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#10.__What_are_some_of_the_differences_between_using_SQLite_and_H) by default, and we can access other [functions](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html) not available in SQLite:

In this example we can use `CONCAT`:

```
library(RH2)
library(sqldf
sqldf("SELECT CONCAT(SP1, '-' , SP2) AS SP FROM df")
```

Output:

```
      SP
1 521-526
2 521-523
```

If we need to convert columns to character:

```
# Using sqldf alone   
sqldf("SELECT CAST(SP1 as text) FROM df")
# RH2 loaded
sqldf("SELECT TO_CHAR(SP1) FROM df")
```